# How to generate dynamic strings in javascript closure call

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm creating a long list of select items and wanted to create a closure call to add each option, then queue the call (via a setTimer) so the browser would not hang.

My implementation works great, but here is what has me puzzled, the following code:

```
var mainList = $('#mainList');
for (var i=0;i < 100000; i++) {
  var self = mainList, addOption = function() {
    $(self).append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
   };

  $.queue.add(addOption, this);
}
```

generates:

```
<option value='100000'>100000</option>
<option value='100000'>100000</option>
<option value='100000'>100000</option>  etc...
```

Where I would like to have it generate the options:

```
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>  etc...
```

I'm struggling with how the closure is executed, it makes sense that the addOption() method is called when i == 100000, but I would like the call to reflect the value of i at the time it is queued up.

Is there an easy trick I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `addOption` by [**IIFE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) which returns a function

```
var mainList = $('#mainList');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var self = mainList,
        addOption = (function(i) {
            return function() {
                $(self).append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
            }
        })(i);
    $.queue.add(addOption, this);
}
```

Comment: Pure awesomeness @AmmarCSE, thanks a lot.  I'm going to read up on the IIFE and how the js executes right now, that's exactly the functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to the introduction of [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), it was certainly necessary to employ a closure specifically to trap one or more vars in situations like this.

Now, that approach is considered to be a bit clumsy.

You can define a basic `addOption` function, then spawn versions of it in the loop, using `addOption.bind()` to bind in both `mainList` as "thisArg", and `i` as the first formal variable :

```
var mainList = $('#mainList');
var addOption = function(i) {
    this.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
};
for (var i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    $.queue.add(addOption.bind(mainList, i), this);
}
```

Comment: That's very nice and looks cleaner (and easier to read) than my older way.  Thanks!